# How to get rid of LD_PRELOAD when using JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have JNI library libA.so, which depends on a C library libB.so.

In Java, one way to resolve "symbol lookup error" is to have:

```
class A{
    public native void g();
    static{
        System.load("/asdfghjk/libA.so");
    }
}
```

Then run the java program with

```
LD_PRELOAD=libB.so
```

However, this hack cannot be used in production system, for example when the program is deployed with Tomcat JSF.

The following "solution" doesn't work:

```
class A{
    public native void g();
    static{
        System.load("/asdfghjk/libB.so");
        System.load("/asdfghjk/libA.so");
    }
}
```

It produces an error:

```
symbol lookup error: /blah/... undefined symbol: _ZNblahblahblah...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error is because it can't find libraries which your shared library depends on.

You should either add the location of dependent libraries to your `java.library.path`, explicitly `System.load` them first in the right order, or somehow use the `dlopen` system call to load the dependencies.

This question may be helpful: [Java: load shared librariees with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425034/java-load-shared-librariees-with-dependencies)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Creating another wrapper for dlopen solves the problem. But that error was not because Java couldn't find the libraries which the shared library is depending on, thus editing java.library.path was no use. It is because the dependent library (libB.so) is loaded, the symbols *are* resolved but not made to be globally available for the running process. Can you edit your answer so I can tick it?

Comment: Feel free to answer yourself, I don't mind. My answer probably still applies to situations giving these kind of symptoms in some cases.