# Dynamic loading library with different name at runtime

Tags: c++, g++, dynamic-linking, rocksdb, dynamic-loading

Is it possible to build a shared library (with g++) that has a dependency on another shared library (in my case RocksDB - `librocksdb.so`), but whose file name at runtime is different? (e.g. `librocksdb1234.so`). And if so, how can this be done?

**More Context**

1. I'm implementing a custom compaction filter for RocksDB (C++) that I intend to use in my Java application via JNI.
2. When using RocksDB in Java I need to first invoke `RocksDB.loadLibrary()`, which will load the RocksDB library. The RocksDB JNI jar comes with multiple RocksDB shared objects (.so files), one for each architecture. When I call this method it will select the correct shared object file in the jar, copy it to a temporary folder, and load it using `System.load(...)`. The copied shared object file **is created with a random suffix**.
3. For the development of the custom compaction filter, I first installed RocksDB headers (this is simply a call to a Makefile task in the RocksDB project, that will copy the headers to `/usr/local/include/rocksdb`), and also built RocksDB as a shared library and installed it in `/usr/local/lib` (again, this is just a call to a Makefile task that already exists in the project).
4. To build the shared library with the custom compaction filter, I'm using g++ as follows (for linking): `g++ -shared -fPI -Wl,--no-undefined <list-of-object-files> -o libcustom.so -lrocksdb` (the installed RocksDB shared library is named `librocksdb.so`).
5. When I try to load my shared library with the custom compaction filter on my Java application it is successfully loaded as expected (as long as the `librocksdb.so` is present).
6. But since RocksDB JNI already comes with the RocksDB shared object files, what I want is to just use those shared objects, and not the `librocksdb.so` that I installed for development purposes. So, I basically just delete the `librocksdb.so` and add the call to `RocksDB.loadLibrary()` in my Java application. Once I do this, I stop being able to load my shared library due to `librocksdb.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.
7. I validated that the RocksDB shared object (from the jar) was properly loaded using `lsof -p <pid>`.
8. From what I understand, this happens because my shared object with the custom compaction filter will have an entry in its header that defines a dependency on a library named `rocksdb` (confirmed using `objdump -x ...`). But because the RocksDB shared object loaded by `RocksDB.loadLibrary()` has a random name, it won't match the needed dependency.

```
Dynamic Section:
  NEEDED               librocksdb.so.6
...
```

**Side question**
In point 8. I'm assuming that the dynamic loading will be based on the file name of the shared object. Is this a correct assumption? Or will the dynamic loading be based on the SONAME? (I noticed that the shared objects in the RocksDB JNI jar don't have the SONAME defined).

Comment: If you just need to run on linux you could probably `LD_PRELOAD` to hook `dlopen` and redirect the underlying call that `System.load` makes to point to the system install of `librocksdb`. This is a kind of ugly way of doing it though.

Comment: If you use glibc, you can call `dl_iterate_phdr` and find out which shared libraries are loaded.

Comment: It might be worth looking into `dlopen()` and `dlsym()` (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), which are functions to manually load shared libraries and retrieve function pointers from them.

Answer (score 1):

> To build the shared library with the custom compaction filter, I'm using g++ as follows

Note that *IF* you guarantee that all symbols from `librocksdb.so.6` needed by your library are already present before your library is loaded, *THEN* you don't have to link your shared library with `librocksdb` at all. Simply remove `-lrocksdb` from your link command line, and it will load just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to remove the `-lrocksdb` but it now fails loading the library with `undefined symbol: _ZNK7rocksdb12Customizable9GetOptionERKNS_13ConfigOptionsERKSsPSs`. I searched for the symbol in the shared object from the jar with `nm -gD` and it exists.

Comment: Here's the output from `nm -gD ... | grep _ZNK7rocksdb12Customizable9GetOptionERKNS_13ConfigOptionsERKSsPSs` for the `librocksdb` (first) and from my shared library: `00000000005577e0 T _ZNK7rocksdb12Customizable9GetOptionERKNS_13ConfigOptionsERKSsPSs
` versus `U _ZNK7rocksdb12Customizable9GetOptionERKNS_13ConfigOptionsERKSsPSs
`.

Comment: Also, running: `LD_PRELOAD=/.../librocksdbjni-linux64.so ldd -r libcustom.so` shows no undefined symbols. Where `librocksdbjni-linux64.so` is basically the RocksDB shared library in the jar.

Comment: It seems that the issue is similar to the one mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425034/java-load-shared-libraries-with-dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding rocksdb specifically, if you have the rocksdb **jni** share library that you link at build time in one directory, you can set `java.library.path` to include the directory, then the library will be loaded with its real filenames instead of a temporary one with random suffix.