# Java JNI UnsatisfiedLinkError on Linux when loading multiple libraries

Tags: java, linux, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

```
public class Foo {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("lib1");
        System.loadLibrary("lib2");
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Getting a ULE on lib2 load for a public static bool member field that's defined in the lib1's bss section according to nm. Both are shared libraries. lib1 successfully loads according to Xlog:library=info. Any ideas what can be causing this?

Comment: Please be less vague and show the actual code and error.

Comment: This looks like a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425034/java-load-shared-libraries-with-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using JNA but this is essentially the same problem and I was able to use a native library loader to work around it as discussed here: [Java: load shared libraries with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425034/java-load-shared-libraries-with-dependencies)